# ProFormUploadButton can't change text

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

ProFormUploadButton text is stuck with 单击上传 does anyone have any idea how to change it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

just add title

example:

```
         <ProFormUploadButton
            label="upload"
            }
            maxCount={1}
            action=""
            title="upload"
            }
            customRequest={(fileInfo) => {
              fileInfo.onSuccess();
              return true;
            }}
            name="icon_file"
          />
```